# How can add the Websevice to my C# Form Application

Tags: c#

I had created a webservice , "service.asmx" and i need to add this service into my C# form application .

Answer (score 1):

Use Add Web/Service Reference option in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

1. Host the webservice in IIS.
2. Right click on your project > Add Web Reference -> Find the webservice -> Click add

Comment: There is no need to host in IIS, can use self host, or in VS default web server of VS.